# Break out from If statement in ActionScript3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, if-statement

I try to write a small Android program, which tells me the distance from a fix point. When the distance of the device and the fix point is below 100meters, a phone plays a sound.

```
if (distance<100){mySound.Play()};
```

It's OK, the sound starts, but when the GPS send the new coordinates, and the distance is below 100meters again, the mySound starts again and again in each second. The Sound should be played only one, when the the distance decrase below 100metes at First time. Any advice? Thx!

```
var soundPlayed:Boolean=false;    
public function GPS_frissit(event:GeolocationEvent):void
{
    var R = 6371; // km
    var dLat = (47.507105-event.latitude)*Math.PI/180;
    var dLon = (19.024519-event.longitude)*Math.PI/180;
    var lat1 = (event.latitude)*Math.PI/180;
    var lat2 = 47.507105*Math.PI/180;

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;
    var e = Math.round(d*1000);
    var tavolsag:String;

    var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
    mySound.load(new URLRequest("sound.mp3"));

    if (e < 100 && soundPlayed == false){
        soundPlayed == true;
        mySound.play();
    }

    if (e >= 100){
        soundPlayed = false;
    }

    if (e <100){    
        tavolsag = "X";
    }

    else if (e > 100)   
    {
        tavolsag = "Y";
    }
    document.write(tavolsag);
}
```

Comment: **(1)** Make `soundPlayed` as either a **public** or **private** var so it's available to other functions. **(2)** Better use a `soundChannel` to stop/start/pause any playback of a `Sound` object. **(3)** I suggest having a separate loadSound function that prepares & decodes so that later your `GPS_frissit` simply just plays it when needed, right now you make multiple new copies of exact same sound in Ram. Make one load and re-play it many times. **(4)** I suggest you embed the mp3 as a class within your code so that your app code & mp3 are compiled together as one unit. Check online for this.

Comment: Also `soundPlayed == true;` really should be `soundPlayed = true;`... When you say `soundPlayed = false;` make sure you also do something (code) to actually stop the sound..

Answer (score 2):

Just use a Boolean. This is sometimes referred to as a flag or flag state.

```
if (dist < 100 && soundPlayed == false){
    soundPlayed = true;
    mySound.play();
}
```

then

```
if (dist >= 100){
    soundPlayed = false;
}
```

you just need to add a variable to you class called `var soundPlayed:Boolean = false;`

Comment: THx! Where to place the `var soundPlayed:Boolean = false;` variable? I've put outside the `public function GPS_refresh(event:GeolocationEvent):void` not to change the value back to false, but the sound starts again.

Comment: Put it inside the package but outside of any functions. Even outside and before your main document constructor.